# Prove or disprove: If [a]=[b] in $Z_{n}$, then $(a,n)=(b,n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

This is what I have so far. I know the beginning part is correct, but I crash towards the end.

By Theorem 2.3, we have $[a]=[b]$, so $a \equiv b (mod n)$. Now, by the Congruence Class definition, $n \vert a-b$ so there exists an integer s such that

$a-b=ns \rightarrow a=ns+b$ or $a-ns=b$.

Either any integer that divides b and n divides a or any integers that divides a and n divides b, so $(a,n)=(b,n)$

I am really bothered by my last sentence. Apparently, gcd(a,n)=gcd(b,n), but how? Does it have something to do with the integers n, a, and b? Like...common divisors from the equation a=ns+b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $a = ns + b$. So if $x$ is the greatest common divisor of both $a$ and $n$, then we see that $x$ must also be a divisor of $b$ (since it must be a divisor of both summands). Conversely, if $x$ is the greatest common divisor of both $b$ and $n$, then we see that $x$ is also a divisor of $a$. Therefore, we must have that $\gcd(a,n) = \gcd(b,n)$.

Comment: I actually had those sentences in my notebook prior to typing it out Latex, but I referred a and n as integers for one case and b and n as integers in another case. 
It was like any integer that divides b and n divides a for a-ns=b.
And then for a=ns+b any integer that divides a and n divides b

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's right. A slightly cleaner way to say it is, since $a-ns=b$, letting $d$ to be a common divisor of $a$ and $n$, $d|b$. But also $d|n$, so $d$ is divisible by $\gcd(b,n)$. This is true for any common divisor $d$ so in particular true for $\gcd(a,n)$, implying $\gcd(b,n)|\gcd(a,n)$. The other way follows by analogous argument.

Answer (score 0):

Write $u=\gcd(a,n)$ and $v=\gcd(b,n)$. We know that $u|a,n$. Thus $u|a,ns$, so $$u|a-ns=b.$$ Therefore $u|n,b$ and, by definition of $v$, $u|v$. In particular $u\leq v$. Similarly, $v\leq u$ and it follows that $u=v$.